# How to get the Base URL including the context for the storefront?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

How to get the Base URL including the context for the storefront?

For example, for this URL

```
https://spartacus.c39j2-walkersde1-d4-public.model-t.cc.commerce.ondemand.com/electronics-spa/en/USD/OpenCatalogue/Cameras/Digital-Cameras/Digital-SLR/c/578
```

How do I get just

```
https://spartacus.c39j2-walkersde1-d4-public.model-t.cc.commerce.ondemand.com/electronics-spa/en/USD/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get separately the origin (`https://s(...).com`) and the context URL parameters (`electronics-spa/en/USD/`).

#### The origin

```js
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
// ...
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any){}
//...
const origin = this.document.location.origin;
// "https://s(...).com"
```

*Note: it won't work in Server Side Rendering! Please use Spartacus' injection token `SERVER_REQUEST_ORIGIN` then:*

```js
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { SERVER_REQUEST_OTIGIN } from '@spartacus/core';
// ...
constructor(
   @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any,
   @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId,
   @Inject(SERVER_REQUEST_ORIGIN) private serverRequestOrigin
){}
// ...
let origin;
if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)){
   origin = this.serverRequestOrigin;
} else {
   origin = this.document.location.origin;
}
```

#### The context URL parameters

```js
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
// ...
constructor(private router: Router){}
// ...
const context = router.serializeUrl(router.createUrlTree(''));
// "electronics-spa/en/USD/"
```

#### Final result

```js
const result = `${origin}/${context}`;
// "https://s(...).com/electronics-spa/en/USD/"
```

Comment: For which version is SERVER_REQUEST_ORIGIN, I do not see anything exported?

Comment: 1.4 - see https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/release/1.4.x/projects/core/src/ssr/ssr.providers.ts#L13

but not <1.4 - see https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/release/1.3.x/projects/core/src/ssr/ssr.providers.ts#L13